# Pyspark: No suitable Driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting the following error `SQLException: No suitable driver`

I have the spark class set in my code as the following:
`os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--driver-class-path /path/to/driver/jars --jars /file/path/to/jars'`

And when I call spark-submit I specify the jars to make sure that they're found.
`spark-submit --driver-class-path /Users/my_user/tools/spark-3.12-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/postgresql-42.2.23.jar --jars /Users/my_user/tools/spark-3.12-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/postgresql-42.2.23.jar postgres_elt.py`

I then put my driver and executor in my `spark-default template` but I'm still getting the same error.

I'm trying to connect to AWS from my local machine. Not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this issue, I added `.option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")` to my variable. This seemed to have fixed my issue and I was able to connect without a problem.